# Page Break after string like value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to insert a page break after any cell that contains the word `"Page"`. The full value from the cell would be something like `~"Page: # of #"`.

```
Dim value1 As String
Range("A1").Select
For Each Cell In Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

If Cell.Value Like "Page:*" Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
```

This code will run through each but not compare properly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim value1 As String
    Range("A1").Select
    For Each Cell In Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If Cell.Value Like "Page:*" Then
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Cell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Needed appended to yours. Thanks!

'End If'
        'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select'
'Next'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code in your previous answer works. This is the code you need to use:

Dim cellval As Range
      Range("A1").Select

```
  For Each cellval In Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    If Left(cellval.Value, 4) = "Page" Then

         ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add cellval.Offset(1, 0)

    End If


  Next
```

The wildcard character and SQL type testing doesn't work in Excel. YOu have to parse the string to determine what is in the cell.

Also there it is unnecessary to select the row and then act upon it. You can act on it directly as I show in the loop and the HPageBreaks object you want to work with is part of the Active worksheet which makes it more direct.

Finally, just as a best practice you do not want to be changing the Activecell with selects inside of the loop like you were trying to do as it could cause errors. Let the loop change the cells and use your index to do the heavy lifting

Good luck